# Finding singular root terms by dominant balance method

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the problem
$$ε^2x^3 + x^2 −4 = 0$$ where $0 < ε <<1$. The two regular roots of this problem are $$x = ±2−2ε^2±5ε^4$$ Find the ﬁrst two non-zero terms in the asymptotic expansion for the singular root as $ε →0^+$.

Hint: It is possible for many terms in the expansion to be $0$.

To find singular, we rescale and write $x=\delta X$ with $X=O(1)$ to give $$ε^2\delta^3 X^3 + \delta^2 X^2 −4 = 0$$

Try $\varepsilon^2 \delta ^3$ ~ $\delta ^2$ $\implies$ $\delta$ ~ $1/\varepsilon^2$.

So we have $$X^3 + X^2 -4\varepsilon^4=0$$

Write $X=X_0 +\varepsilon X_1 +\varepsilon^2 X_2+O(\varepsilon ^3)$.

$O(1):X_0^3 +X_0^2=0$ so $X_0=0,-1$

$O(\varepsilon^2):X_1=0$

$O(\varepsilon^4):X_2^2-4=0$ so $X_2=2,-2$

Have I done everything correct so far? Which solutions do we ignore and why??

Comment: can someone help please?

Comment: we expect that singular solution blow up at $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ therefore you can kick the one with $X_0=0$

Comment: @tired What about the $X_2=2,-2$? Which one can we kick?

Comment: Better: Looking at the structure of our rescaled equation we expect that the root gets imaginary at some point. This is consistent with a vanishing of your approximate solution. Therefore we need $X_2=2$

Comment: @tired ok so now we have $X=-1+2\varepsilon^2 +O(\varepsilon^3)$ giving the singular root as $x=2-1/\varepsilon^2+O(\varepsilon^3)$ correct??

Comment: i haven't checked your calculations in detail, but the root should be same as obtained by @Claude Leibovici: $x \approx -1/\epsilon^2 +4\epsilon^2$

Comment: I don't understand how you get that at the end... please help.

Comment: check your calculations, this looks like a minor mistake.

Comment: I really can't see! After we get the X value, we multiply that by delta since the singular is x=delta*X which gives what I got.... since we turn delta into 1/epsilon^2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the equation $$ε^2x^3 + x^2 −4 = 0$$ you properly found $$x_1=2−2ε^2+5ε^4$$ $$x_2= -2−2ε^2-5ε^4$$ and you know that the sum of the roots is $-\frac 1{\epsilon^2}$. So $$x_3=4 \epsilon^2-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$  Let us check using $\epsilon=10^{-2}$. Using Cardano, the "exact" solutions are $$x_1=+1.999800050$$ $$x_2=-2.000200050$$ $$x_3=-9999.999600$$ and  the above developments give exactly the same values (for ten significant figures).

Comment: would you be able to show me the dominant balance way please??

Comment: I have had an attempt with the balance way. Please can you or anyone else look at it and help me